# S21 Bluetooth interrupted by youtube links

Tags: youtube, bluetooth-audio, twitter, samsung-galaxy-s-21

In twitter, when scrolling thru tweets containing youtube links, bluetooth automatically attaches to the link ready to play it. This interrupts whatever was being listened to, even though I dont click the link to actually listen. Is there a way to prevent bluetooth anticipating my wanting to play the youtube in that way, so it doesn’t interrupt until I actually click the video link?

Comment: Solved! https://www.theverge.com/21422932/autoplay-videos-how-to-facebook-twitter-reddit-chrome-safari-edge-firefox

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Looks like you've found the solution by yourself, which is great! Consider posting it as a proper answer since [self-answering is not only allowed, but even encouraged](//android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Thanks!